How do you add test coverage for `.transfer()` calls with foundry?
I have some solidity that looks like this:
        if (mintprice > 0 ) {
            payable(ownerTreasury()).transfer(mintprice * amount);
        }

My goal is to write some test coverage to check two cases:

mintprice === 0
mintprice > 0

In the first case, I want to assert that the payable(ownerTreasury()).transfer(...) call is not reached.
In the second case, I want to assert that the payable(ownerTreasury()).transfer(...) completes successfully (assuming that the msg.sender and msg.values are correct).
The test case I'm stuck on is the mintprice === 0 case -- I'm not sure how to check for whether or not the .transfer() call is happening.
First attempt
I've tried testing with the foundry cheatcode expectCall like this:
   function test_mint_ShouldNotCallTransferOnOwnerTreasuryIfMintPriceIs0() public {
        // Owner: Set up TOKEN_ID_2 to be ready to mint
        vm.prank(OWNER);
        minterV1.launchMintForId(TOKEN_ID_2, 0); // mint price is 0

        // User: Mint 1 copy of tokenId 2, expect transfer not to be called
        vm.startPrank(CAMPAIGN_USER);
        vm.expectCall(address(OWNER_TREASURY), abi.encodeWithSelector(transfer.selector), 0);
        minterV1.mint{value: PLATFORM_FEE}(TOKEN_ID_2, 1, "");
        vm.stopPrank();

        // Owner: Turn off minting for TOKEN_ID_2
        vm.prank(OWNER);
        minterV1.setMintingStatusForId(TOKEN_ID_2, false);

        // Owner: Change mint price to 0.01
        vm.prank(OWNER);
        minterV1.setMintPriceForId(TOKEN_ID_2, 0.01);

        // Owner: Turn minting back on
        vm.prank(OWNER);
        minterV1.setMintingStatusForId(TOKEN_ID_2, true);
        
        // User: Mint 1 copy of tokenId 2, expect transfer to be called
        vm.startPrank(CAMPAIGN_USER);
        vm.expectCall(address(OWNER_TREASURY), abi.encodeWithSelector(transfer.selector), 0.01 ether);
        minterV1.mint{value: 0.01}(TOKEN_ID_2, 1, "");
        vm.stopPrank();
    }   

but the issue with this is that transfer.selector is.. not really a thing:
forge test --match-test test_mint_ShouldNotCallTransferOnOwnerTreasuryIfMintPriceIs0
Compiler run failed:
Error (7576): Undeclared identifier.
   --> test/MinterImplementationV1/Mint.t.sol:123:71:
    |
123 |         vm.expectCall(address(OWNER_TREASURY), abi.encodeWithSelector(transfer.selector), 0);
    |                                                                       ^^^^^^^^

Error (7576): Undeclared identifier.
   --> test/MinterImplementationV1/Mint.t.sol:141:71:
    |
141 |         vm.expectCall(address(OWNER_TREASURY), abi.encodeWithSelector(transfer.selector), 0.01 ether);
    |                                                                       ^^^^^^^^

Error:
Compilation failed

Second attempt
So then I tried a different approach by trying to encode the function signature(?) of the transfer function and then running vm.expectCall on that:
    function test_mint_ShouldCallTransferToOwnerTreasuryWhenMintPriceMoreThan0() public {
        // User: Mint 1 copy of tokenId 2, expect transfer to be called
        vm.startPrank(CAMPAIGN_USER);
        vm.expectCall(address(OWNER_TREASURY), abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,uint256)"), 1);
        minterV1.mint{value: 0.01 ether + PLATFORM_FEE}(TOKEN_ID_1, 1, "");
        vm.stopPrank();
    }

    function test_mint_ShouldNotCallTransferOnOwnerTreasuryIfMintPriceIs0() public {
        // Owner: Set up TOKEN_ID_2 to be ready to mint
        vm.prank(OWNER);
        minterV1.launchMintForId(TOKEN_ID_2, 0); // mint price is 0

        // User: Mint 1 copy of tokenId 2, expect transfer not to be called
        vm.startPrank(CAMPAIGN_USER);
        vm.expectCall(address(OWNER_TREASURY), abi.encodeWithSignature("transfer(address,uint256)"), 0);
        minterV1.mint{value: PLATFORM_FEE}(TOKEN_ID_2, 1, "");
        vm.stopPrank();
    }   

This doesn't quite work either. The "transfer was not called" case works well...
forge test --match-test test_mint_ShouldNotCallTransferOnOwnerTreasuryIfMintPriceIs0
[⠊] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped

Ran 1 test for test/MinterImplementationV1/Mint.t.sol:Mint
[PASS] test_mint_ShouldNotCallTransferOnOwnerTreasuryIfMintPriceIs0() (gas: 189310)
Suite result: ok. 1 passed; 0 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 1.58ms (126.54µs CPU time)

Ran 1 test suite in 393.26ms (1.58ms CPU time): 1 tests passed, 0 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

but the "transfer was called" case is incorrect:
forge test --match-test test_mint_ShouldCallTransferToOwnerTreasuryWhenMintPriceMoreThan0
[⠊] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped

Ran 1 test for test/MinterImplementationV1/Mint.t.sol:Mint
[FAIL. Reason: expected call to 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002 with data 0xa9059cbb to be called 1 time, but was called 0 times] test_mint_ShouldCallTransferToOwnerTreasuryWhenMintPriceMoreThan0() (gas: 191554)
Suite result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 skipped; finished in 12.45ms (2.63ms CPU time)

Ran 1 test suite in 354.99ms (12.45ms CPU time): 0 tests passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped (1 total tests)

Failing tests:
Encountered 1 failing test in test/MinterImplementationV1/Mint.t.sol:Mint
[FAIL. Reason: expected call to 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002 with data 0xa9059cbb to be called 1 time, but was called 0 times] test_mint_ShouldCallTransferToOwnerTreasuryWhenMintPriceMoreThan0() (gas: 191554)

Encountered a total of 1 failing tests, 0 tests succeeded

Is there another way to check for the transfer call? Am I going about this wrong?
Any advice would be helpful, thanks! I'm just trying to be thorough with my testing (and get better at foundry) .

You wouldn't use expectCall to test a native transfer function. You'd instead just compare balances. Using transfer you don't call a function, you use native gas, which doesn't work so great with the Call functionality you're looking to use.
For example, let's say this is your minter:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Minter {
    uint256 public amount = 10;
    address public ownerTreasury = address(56);

    function sendMint(uint256 mintprice) public {
        if (mintprice > 0) {
            payable(ownerTreasury).transfer(mintprice * amount);
        }
    }
}

Your test would look something like this:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import {Test, console} from "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {Minter} from "../src/Counter.sol";

contract MinterTest is Test {
    Minter public minter;

    function setUp() public {
        minter = new Minter();
    }

    function testTransferCalled() public {
        // Arrange
        vm.deal(address(minter), 5e18);
        address ownerTreasury = minter.ownerTreasury();
        uint256 startingBalance = address(ownerTreasury).balance;

        // Act
        uint256 mintP = 1;
        minter.sendMint(mintP);

        // Assert
        assertEq(address(ownerTreasury).balance, startingBalance + (mintP * minter.amount()));
    }
}


That’s what I’d already answered, sensei!

As far as I know, built-in functions in Solidity for sending ether like transfer, send, and call do not have a function signature or selector, because they are not part of the contract's ABI.
And, the calling of transfer that is shown in the Foundry doc corresponding to expectCall, is showcasing the transfer of a non-native token like ERC-20, ERC-721, etc.
So, I think the easiest way to test whether the transfer is called or not, is by comparing the previous and new ether balances.
The revised tests would be:
function test_mint_ShouldCallTransferToOwnerTreasuryWhenMintPriceMoreThan0() public {
    uint256 mintprice = 0.01 ether;
    uint256 amount = 1;

    // User: Mint 1 copy of tokenId 2, expect transfer to be called
    uint256 prevBalance = address(OWNER_TREASURY).balance;
    vm.startPrank(CAMPAIGN_USER);
    minterV1.mint{value: mintprice + PLATFORM_FEE}(TOKEN_ID_1, amount, "");
    vm.stopPrank();
    uint256 newBalance = address(OWNER_TREASURY).balance;
    assertEq(newBalance, prevBalance + ((mintprice + amount) + PLATFORM_FEE ));
}

function test_mint_ShouldNotCallTransferOnOwnerTreasuryIfMintPriceIs0() public {
    uint256 mintprice = 0;
    uint256 amount = 1;

    // Owner: Set up TOKEN_ID_2 to be ready to mint
    vm.prank(OWNER);
    minterV1.launchMintForId(TOKEN_ID_2, mintprice); // mint price is 0

    // User: Mint 1 copy of tokenId 2, expect transfer not to be called
    uint256 prevBalance = address(OWNER_TREASURY).balance;
    vm.startPrank(CAMPAIGN_USER);
    minterV1.mint{value: PLATFORM_FEE}(TOKEN_ID_2, amount, "");
    vm.stopPrank();
    uint256 newBalance = address(OWNER_TREASURY).balance;
    assertEq(newBalance, prevBalance + PLATFORM_FEE);
}

NOTE: I've assumed that the PLATFORM_FEE is getting added into the contract's (i.e., OWNER_TREASURY) balance. So, you can change it as per your logic.

I appreciate this approach for testing the impact of .transfer in general -- however in this specific case, I want to ensure that even when we're calling .transfer on a value of 0, the .transfer or the internal transaction is not added to the user's gas costs at all. Is there a way to do that?

also how did you get syntax highlighting to work? :D

If you pass the value as 0, then the prevBalance would be equal to newBalance, so the comparison of balances would still be applicable.

For syntax highlighting, just before starting the code block, use triple backticks (```) followed by the language name (or short name) like js, and then at the end of the code block, enclose it with triple backticks again. As, solidity is not recognized, so here also you can just use js.

By the way, if the Minter contract isn’t pre-funded (that you can achieve using vm.deal) with the amount that is being transferred to OWNER_TREASURY, then it would throw the "transfer amount exceeds balance" error, when the value is passed as 0.


if the Minter contract isn’t pre-funded (that you can achieve using vm.deal) with the amount that is being transferred to OWNER_TREASURY, then it would throw the "transfer amount exceeds balance" error

ahhh this is super helpful actually, I think I was overcomplicating my setup by testing with cases where the contract call had some non-zero msg.value
going to try this!

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
